# Adding values to a columns based on other columns in the same dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My aim is to put values in column D based on columns A to C. I want to go through each of the columns A, B and C and add 1 to column D if the value is greater than 20.

```
import pandas as pd
data={'A':[5,2,25,4],"B":[15,22,100,24], "C":[4, 100, 0, 19], "D" : [0,0,0,0]}
df= pd.DataFrame(data)

for x in range(0, len(df.columns)):
    if df.iloc[:, x]  > 20:
        df["D"] = df["D"] +1
    else:
        df["D"] = df["D"]
df
```

So, based on the sample code, Column D should looks like:

| D |
| --- |
| 0 |
| 2 |
| 2 |
| 1 |

However, I keep getting this error - ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
I have gone through other answers here ([Truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921951/truth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous-use-a-empty-a-bool-a-item-a-any-o)) which indicate that it is a  multiple operator issue but I am not using these here.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is wrong is that you can't use `if Series > value` in a vectorial way. `if` expects a single boolean value and `df.iloc[:, x]  > 20` returns a Series of booleans.

In your case use:

```
df['D'] = df.drop(columns='D').gt(20).sum(1)
```

*NB. If column D is initially null or inexistent, skip the `.drop(columns='D')`.*

Output:

```
    A    B    C  D
0   5   15    4  0
1   2   22  100  2
2  25  100    0  2
3   4   24   19  1
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution:

```
df.D = (
  df.loc[:, ~ df.columns.str.contains('D')]
  .apply(lambda x: sum(x > 20), axis = 1))
```

Output:

```
    A    B    C  D
0   5   15    4  0
1   2   22  100  2
2  25  100    0  2
3   4   24   19  1
```